# GDB/C++ - How to hide const static fields when backtracing?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm debugging c++ code with gdb. Something is throwing a wobbly, so I hit "backtrace full" to inspect. Unfortunately some of the member variables are instances of class that contain `const static` fields. There are a lot of `const static` fields. In addition, these `const static` fields are themselves instances of said class:

```
class foo {
public:
   int val;
   foo(int _val) : val(_val) {}

   static const foo FOO_5 = foo(5);
   static const foo FOO_6 = foo(6);
   static const foo FOO_7 = foo(7);
   ...
   }
```

(My real code is a font formatting class with presets for bold, italic, black, red, etc)

The result is gdb feeling the need to spit out every `const static` field of every member of said class (and every member of each memeber, etc). This results in many screens full of the same `const static` fields being displayed:

Wall of gdb text:

```
 mItems = std::vector of length 0, capacity 0, activeFormat = {
            _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', 
            a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 0 '\000', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
            static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
            static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
            static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = {
              _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', 
              a = 255 '\377', format = 1 '\001', flags = 0 '\000', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
              static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
              static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
              static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = {
                _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', 
                a = 255 '\377', format = 2 '\002', flags = 0 '\000', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
                static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
                static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static underline = {
                  _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', 
                  a = 255 '\377', format = 4 '\004', flags = 0 '\000', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                  static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
                  static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
                  static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                  static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                  static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static strikethrough = {
                    _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', 
                    a = 255 '\377', format = 8 '\b', flags = 0 '\000', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                    static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
                    static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
                    static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                    static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                    static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                    static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = {
                      _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 0 '\000', b = 0 '\000', 
                      a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                      static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
                      static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
                      static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = {
                        _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 0 '\000', g = 255 '\377', b = 0 '\000', 
                        a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                        static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', 
                        static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', 
                        static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static blue = {
                          _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 0 '\000', g = 0 '\000', 
                          b = 255 '\377', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", 
                          static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', 
                          static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', 
                          static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                          static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = {
                            _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', 
                            b = 0 '\000', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", 
                            static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', 
                            static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', 
                            static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                            static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
                            y seen type>, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = {
                              _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 0 '\000', g = 0 '\000', b = 0 '\000', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', 
                              static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                              static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                              static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                              static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = {
                                _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                                static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                                static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = {_vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 255 '\377', g = 0 '\000', b = 255 '\377', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', 
                                  flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', 
                                  static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                  static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                  static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                  static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = {
                                    _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 0 '\000', g = 255 '\377', b = 255 '\377', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                                    static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                                    static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                    static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                    static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                    static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = {
                                      _vptr.sttfont_format = 0x555555590898 <vtable for sttfont_format+16>, r = 128 '\200', g = 128 '\200', b = 128 '\200', a = 255 '\377', format = 0 '\000', flags = 1 '\001', padding = "\000", static FORMAT_NONE = 0 '\000', 
                                      static FORMAT_BOLD = 1 '\001', static FORMAT_ITALIC = 2 '\002', static FORMAT_UNDERLINE = 4 '\004', static FORMAT_STRIKETHROUGH = 8 '\b', static FORMAT_RENDER_EVEN_IF_CALLBACK_EXISTS = 128 '\200', static FORMAT_FLAGS_COLOUR_SET = 1 '\001', 
                                      static bold = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                      static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                      static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                      static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                      static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = {<No data fields>}}, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                  static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                                static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                              static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                            static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                          static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                        static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                      static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                    static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                    static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                  static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                  static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, 
                static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
                static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
              static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
              static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
              static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}, static italic = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
            static underline = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static strikethrough = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static red = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static green = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
            static blue = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static yellow = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static black = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static white = <same as static member of an already seen type>, 
            static magenta = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static cyan = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static grey = <same as static member of an already seen type>, static reset = <same as static member of an already seen type>}}
```

My question is simple: **How do I suppress `const static` fields from gdb's `backtrace full` command?** Or even just remove all static fields. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I suppress const static fields from gdb's backtrace full command?

`(gdb) set print static off`